# Android: onOptionsItemSelected doesn't get called from the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I know that this question has already been asked, but none of the proposed solutions work for me.

I want this method to be called from the Fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_clock_layout, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.clock_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new ClockAdapter(this.getActivity()));



        return view; 
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_alarm:
            Fragment newContent = new AddAlarmFragment();
            if (getActivity() instanceof MenuMainActivity) {
                MenuMainActivity mma = (MenuMainActivity) getActivity();
                mma.switchContent(newContent);
            } 
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And then in the `MenuMainActivity` this method gets called:

```
@Override   
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.add_alarm:
        return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This unfortunately, is not working and the Fragment method doesn't get called.

What might the problem be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you inflated the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` with your **menu xml file**?

Comment: @vilpe89 yeah, in my BaseActivity I have this method:

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

Comment: When exactly the Fragment's method doesn't get called?

Comment: @vilpe89 it's not getting called when you click on R.id.add_alarm

Comment: And how have you tested that, logging, breakpoints, or do you just blindly rely that `switchContent()` method does some magical tricks?

Comment: I have used debugging. I set a breakpoint to both onOptionsItemSelected methods, but the program only stepped into the method in the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my mistake. My `Activity` was extending a `SherlockFragmentActivity`, but the Fragment was extending normal `Fragment` instead of `SherlockFragment`. With the `Fragment` extending `SherlockFragment` it works now.
Thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In your fragments `onCreate` make sure you're calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

**EDIT** Please make sure your `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is actually `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item)`. Or update the `import` to this `MenuItem`

Comment: I have called it in onCreateView in the Fragment. Do you mean I should do it there or rather in the MenuMainActivity?

Comment: I'm always calling it in fragments `onCreate`. Don't call this in the activity

Comment: I edited my answer and posted more code to make it clearer. I am calling the onCreate method too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is the parent of your activities? `FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity`, `SherlockActivity` or `Activity`?

Comment: it's SherlockFragmentActivity

Comment: What theme is your activity using? Does the menu display as an action bar at least?

Comment: yeah, it is displaying as an ActionBar, you can see all the items, i's just when you click on it, onItemClickSelected of the Activity is getting called, but not the one of the fragment

Comment: Try to remove the handling of `R.id.add_alarm` from activity since the activity handles this first. Leaving this out and giving the fragment the chance to handle it may solve it

Comment: yeah, I also tried doing that, but it's not working either :(

Comment: hmmm ... try to override `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` in the fragment instead of overriding `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Also, what version of Sherlock library are you using? latest?

Comment: but there is no such method for a fragment, there is only onOptionsItemSelected :/

Comment: I guess so ... Latest version of this library?

Comment: Edited the answer ... this definatelly must be it! :)

Comment: I found the problem. My Activity was extending a SherlockFragmentActivity, but the Fragment was extending normal Fragment instead of SherlockFragment. With the Fragment extending SherlockFragment it works now. Thanks for your help! Edit your answer if you want me to approve it :)

Comment: It wouldn't be fair ... you can very well upvote my answer and it will be enough. Please provide also your own answer and mark that as accepted.

Comment: Didn't the compiler complain when you extended from a normal fragment in the first case?

Comment: I don't understand how come a `FragmentActivity` can use an `android.app.Fragment` since its support `FragmentManager` handles only `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.